# Execute function after another function containing settimeout completes

Tags: javascript, settimeout

How can I execute a function after another function containing `settimeout` completes?

```
function A(callback) {
  callback();
}  

function B(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(); }, 1000);
}

function C(callback) {
  callback();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You already seem to be set up to use callbacks? A callback will work fine.

Comment: What's your issue here, you already do it with the callback, no ?

Comment: I stored all these functions in an array and was iterating over them to  execute but callback not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I created a function and passed the first element of the array and then recursively called the same function.